# Difference between candidate key & primary key

Tags: database-design, database-theory

What is the differences between candidate key and primary key?

Comment: Same question, asked and answered over in SE.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813363/what-is-the-difference-between-a-candidate-key-and-a-primary-key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [this post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/22/sql-server-difference-candidate-keys-primary-key-simple-words/) does a pretty good job of explaining the difference.

To summarize:

**Candidate Key** – A Candidate Key can be any column or a combination of columns that can qualify as unique key in database. There can be multiple Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can qualify as Primary Key.

**Primary Key** – A Primary Key is a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identify a record. Only one Candidate Key can be Primary Key.

A table can have multiple Candidate Keys that are unique as single column or combined multiple columns to the table. They are all candidates for Primary Key.

Comment: Important note, - candidate key is a MINIMAL set of fields that quality as a unique key in a database.

Answer (score 2):

Candidate keys can take null values whereas primary keys can never be null. That is also one of the significant differences.

Answer (score -1):

Candidate Key – A Candidate Key can be any column or a combination of columns that can qualify as a unique key in the database. There can be multiple Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can qualify as a Primary Key.

Primary Key – A Primary Key is a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identify a record. Only one Candidate Key can be Primary Key.

Candidate keys can take null values whereas primary keys can never be null. That is also one of the significant differences.